# Product =class .CostliestPro is a method that takes an array .This method still says that I should return a value of type Product

Tags: java, return

Product =class .CostliestPro is a method that takes an array .This method still says that I should return a value of type Product.

```
 public Product CostliestPro(Product[] i){   
        float max=0;  
        for(Product b:i)  
        if(b.getPrice()>max)
        max=b.getPrice();
        for(Product:i)
            if(b.getPrice()==max)
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your problem? Its not that clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please explain what you try to get. Cloud you share the data which you give the method CostliestPro

Answer (score 1):

You should use brackets EVERYWHERE even when not needed, because that caused you this problem, for example something like this would compile :

```
public Product CostliestPro(Product[] i){   
    float max=0;  
    for(Product b:i){
        if(b.getPrice()>max){
            max=b.getPrice();
        }
    }
    for(Product b:i){
        if(b.getPrice()==max){
            return b;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

However for returning the product with highest price, this is better approach :

```
public Product CostliestPro(Product[] i){   
    float max=0;  
    Product maxProduct = null;
    for(Product b:i){
        if(b.getPrice()>max){
            max=b.getPrice();
            maxProduct = b;
        }
    }

    return maxProduct;
}
```